# Create a 'PWA minimal requirement' SW with workbox in a SPA

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I've a React SPA built with Vite ad I'm trying to make a basic PWA of it. I'm using the 'vite-pwa' plugin that auto inject the manifest and can generate the SW using google workbox behind the scenes.

What I want to achieve is to generate a very basic SW that if offline will respond with a custom fallback html page.

Since 'vite-pwa' relies on the `generateSW` method of workbox, I tried to setup it with the following

```js
workbox: {
  globPatterns: ['**/*.{png,svg,ico,txt,js,html,css}'],
  navigationPreload: true,
  runtimeCaching: [
    {
      handler: 'NetworkOnly',
      urlPattern: ({request}) => request.mode == 'navigate',
      options: {
        precacheFallback: {
          fallbackURL: '/offline.html'
        }
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

The SW gets generated, installs correctly and precache what's needed.
Sadly when I go offline and try to access the page, it seems to respond with the default `index.html` which starts the SPA.

Next I tried the [Offline Page only](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/managing-fallback-responses/#offline-page-only) recipe that, however, does not use `generateSW`.

```js
//sw.ts content

import { NetworkOnly } from 'workbox-strategies';
import { clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core'

declare let self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope

cleanupOutdatedCaches()
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST)

self.skipWaiting()
clientsClaim()

setDefaultHandler(new NetworkOnly());
offlineFallback();
```

The result is the same, when I go offline it responds with the default `index.html`.